# Can I use whatever JDK version I want to create Android apps?

Tags: android

I can use whatever JDK version I want to create Android apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for android development you need either JDK 5 or JDK 6. this will help you better
http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Answer (score 2):

JDK 5 or 6 is required.

For more information see [System Requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html)

Answer (score 1):

Cited from the Android system requirements (http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html):

Other development environments or IDEs

```
JDK 5 or JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it.

Follow, following steps for it,

Right Click on your Project & select Properties.

Then from the left section Select Java Compiler & select the Version of the JDK you installed. If it is already selected then de-select it & try it.